# What do I write in Get method to get user-name from google-plus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby and trying to make a Gem to get user-info from google-plus(using API Key)???...

Comment: Please show us what you tried already and maybe we can suggest something. I don't think you will get any answers if you leave the question like this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a Get request to google-plus API:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userId}
```

To make this request you can use [RestClient gem](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client), it will be as simple as

```
RestClient.get "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/#{userId}"
```